# Unable to use SSL in a .NET Core 5.0 Console with WebAPI after deployment to Windows Server

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I've created a WebAPI .Net 5 App which listens on an HTTPS port 8286. When I run it in Visual Studio everything is good.

Once I do "Publish" and try to run it on our Windows Server 2012 I get a "*Unable to start Kestrel.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'...*"

[image]

I have an SSL certificate installed on the server. It works with IIS and with a .NET 4.8 WebAPI Self hosted OWIN app

Using `netsh http show sslcert` I can see the certificate is bound
[image]

Here is my CreateHostBuilder function:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("USE URLS: https://*:8286/");
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.UseUrls("https://*:8286/");
                });
        }
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. This has nothing to do with Windows Server. You can't use SSL with an invalid certificate, and a self-signed certificate *is* invalid by definition. The error describes how to generate and trust a self-signed certificate,

Comment: Are you using IIS? Kestrel? NGINX? Adding and configuring the certificate is different in each case. Even if you trust the development certificate *browsers* and other servers won't trust it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. My Certificate is not self signed. It is a purchased SSL certificate. It is valid and being used on the same server with a website on IIS. I believe this is Kestrel. I'm running it from the command line

Comment: You can't have both Kestrel and IIS, unless you use IIS as a reverse proxy. If you use IIS in-process or as a reverse proxy you have to load the certificate into IIS. If you use Kestrel alone, you have to load it in `Startup`. All those cases are documented

Comment: You can [configure SSL and certificates in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis#IISManager) in multiple ways, including through the IIS Manager. If you use ASP.NET Core in-process deployment you don't have to make any changes to the ASP.NET Core code

Comment: You are saying that simply having IIS running on the server means I can't use Kestrel? I'm not interested in using IIS

Comment: No, I'm saying that you can't *host* the same web service on two separate servers at the same time. IIS is one web server. Kestrel is another. Way back when, you couldn't deploy ASP.NET Core services to IIS, so IIS was used as a reverse proxy forwarding calls to Kestrel. Since .NET Core 2? 3? , you can use in-process hosting which is a lot faster. You *can* deploy multiple services on IIS, under different virtual directories

Comment: If the service doesn't use IIS at all, it has to load and use the certificate in `Startup.cs`. The article [Configure endpoints for the ASP.NET Core Kestrel web server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configureiconfiguration) shows how to specify the certificate either through settings, by providing the path to the `pfx` file and password, or in code, by loading and using an `X509Certificate2` instance

Comment: Yes. I think your last comment is relevant to my situation. Let me check it out. Thanks

Comment: Hallelujah @PanagiotisKanavos . So I needed to remove  `webBuilder.UseUrls("https://*:8286/");` from my code and add the "Kestrel" section to my appsettings.json and define the Kestrel.Https.Certificate with my pfx file and its password and it now works. Would you like to add an answer so I can accept it

Comment: In a similar case I chose to host all separate services as separate IIS web apps because IIS is more securer and easier to manage than Kestrel. If something goes wrong, IIS will restart the web app while using Kestrel would result in a crash. I have a hosted Blazor WASM application with several other services that I don't want in the host app itself, eg file converters, job schedulers etc

Comment: Thanks. I will check out using it inside IIS.

Comment: If you use Docker or Kubernetes on the other hand, recycling, resiliency etc are handled by the orchestrator so if one service crashes, the orchestrator will restart it.  In that case Kestrel is just fine. You may not even need HTTPS everywhere as Kubernetes essentially creates a "private network" between services and allows only a "gateway" to be accessed from the outside. Of course, setting up Kubernetes is a whole different can of worms ...

Comment: I eventually want to see if can use this with Docker or Kubernetes since it will need to run on multiple servers. But as you say, that is another subject and for a another day.

Comment: Please add your comment with the link to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configureiconfiguration as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so here is the solution when running the app from the command line (which uses the Kestrel Server)

You need to add to your `appsettings.json` the following section

```
"Kestrel": {
"Endpoints": {
  "Http": {
    "Url": "http://*:1111"
  }
  ,
  "Https": {
    "Url": "https://*:2222",
    "Certificate": {
      "Path": "my_ssl.pfx",
      "Password": "my_password"
    }
  }
}}
```

Obviously for this to work you will need the pfx file. This will work even if you deploy to Linux.

BTW, if you add this to `appsettings.json`, it will override the ports in `launchSettings.json` when running from inside Visual Studio